# Reading and writing to xls and doc files in c

Tags: c, file

I have this particular problem where i have to write a c program that reads numerical data from a text file. The data is tab delimited. Here is a sample from the text file.

```
1   23099   345565  345569
2   908     66766   66768
```

This is data for clients and each client has a row.Each column represents customer no.,previous balance,previous reading, current reading.Then i have to generate a doc. document 
that summarizes all this information and calculates the balance   I can write a function that does this but how do i create an xls document
and a word document where all the results are summarized using the program? The text document has only numerical data. Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a csv file and not a xls file.
Office can open those csv files with good results.

And it is way easier to create a ascii text file with commaseparated values, 
than to create something into a closed format like the ms office formats.

Comment: Its the correct way to do it but how do i create the csv file and make it open in excel.Do i use .csv and excel automatically opens it.

Comment: Since the csv is a classical ascii file, you use the normal c file functions and read the file one line at time and then parse the lines into what you would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to create a spreadsheet that contains formulas and formatting, and can be opened by Excel, is to create an [XML Spreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx) file.